# django: replace patterns (deprecated)

Tags: django

patterns has been deprecated in django 1.1 and there's this line I use to share media files in development in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

after the patterns

```
if settings.DEBUG :
    #urlpatterns += patterns('',
    #    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    #)
    urlpatterns.append(
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

the commented part is the old part, my attempt is getting me this error

```
  File "/home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/revamp/urls.py", line 92, in <module>
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Comment: Did I read that right? Django 1.1??? Or is just a typo for 1.11?

Comment: might be 1.11 it's newer than 1.9.8